# How to put textbox value into array only if it has value?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have created many textboxes and I want to put all of the values into array only if they have themselves filled. I need them to work as how checkbox works in HTML (only the checked ones will then put into array). I use PHP language here. How to do that?

This is my simple HTML textbox:

```
<input name="array[]">
```

Would really appreciate for any help you give to me. Much thanks!

Comment: Iterate over array and check with `empty`

Comment: That's what I'm thinking of but I didn't know which function should I use. Now I have my problem solved, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd recommend you change your name to something more readable:

```
<input name="name[]">
```

Next, you want to get your data, I am assuming your form is using `POST`. We're going to store the form data into a `$names` array variable.

```
$names = $_POST['name'];
```

Next, we're going to create a new array variable which will store input values that have data.

`$namesWithData = [];`

We're now going to loop through the `$names` array. This loop will add any fields with data to the `$namesWithData` array.

```
foreach($names as $name) {
   if(!empty($name) {
      array_push($namesWithData, $name);
   }
}
```

The `$namesWithData` array has the data ready to use.

Comment: This really helps me a lot. Didn't know if there is such function like array_push(). Frankly, I am still dumb in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help! :)